# SQL Server 6 months comparison

Tags: sql-server, datetime, dateadd

I am trying to any get data where the paid date is within 6 months prior to the start date.

My current code looks as follows and just wanted to confirm that it is correct.

```
select 
    b.Identifier, 
    SUM(a.Allowed_Total),
    SUM(a.units)AS units_num, 
    SUM(a.events)as events_num 
from 
    uda.finanace AS a
    INNER JOIN #dischargepats AS b ON b.Identifier=a.PersonID 
where 
    a.paid_date>=DATEADD(M, -6, b.startdate)
group by 
    b.Identifier;
```

Comment: Do the totals from your results match your 6 month's totals expected?

Comment: Why are you using left join instead of inner join?

Comment: Having table b in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN pointless unless you are explicitly looking for nulls in table b. I'd have a careful google of the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN..

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand - 2011-09-20](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: I think I worded the question wrong, I have since updated and I see what you are saying about the Inner join so updated that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `b.dateservice>=DATEADD(M, -6, b.dateservice)` always return true?

Use `b.dateservice>=DATEADD(M, -6, getdate())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I have such a hard time wrapping my head around dates, anyways I used this in my where to get what I wanted:

```
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), a.paid_date))BETWEEN DateAdd(month,-6,b.startdate) and b.startdate
```